# SELECT query to find the parameter having unique parameter value

Tags: sql

I have a Table PARAMETERS with NAME and VALUE as a COLUMNS. Please help me with SQL query to solve the below scenario.

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Only the records which are filtered to have only parameters with only one value defined.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: Also the example shows a NON unique value...

Answer (score 1):

Count the distinct values for each parameter and keep only those with 1:

```
select name,  min(value) value
from parameters
group by name
having count(distinct value) = 1
```

or:

```
select name,  min(value) value
from parameters
group by name
having min(value) = max(value)
```

Comment: Why min is used here ?

Comment: It needs an aggregated value and since there is only 1 it does not matter if it is min or max.

Comment: This is the preferred answer because it returns only one row per parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select p.name, p.value
from PARAMETERS p
where not exists (select 1 from PARAMETERS p1 where p1.name = p.name and p1.value <> p.value);
```